# Output $Error using a variable in the array index

Tags: arrays, powershell, error-handling

Have this code, which takes the errors and output the exceptions.

I want to use a variable in the index of an array, but it does not resolve.

```
[int32]$ErrorCounter = $Error.Count
$ErrorResponse = $($Error[($ErrorCounter)].Exception)
Write-Host "$A, $B, $ErrorResponse"
```

This appears in a loop, and the `$error` contains information I want to parse. So it needs to output the latest `$error` entry, not the whole `$error` array.

Comment: `$error[0]` always contains the latest error (if there is one).

Comment: You can also do: `$Error | ForEach-Object { "$_" }` which will grab all the exception messages.  Not sure why you're doing all that extra work or what `$A`/`$B` represent.

Comment: Its part of a invoke-webrequest loop, where a proxy returns an error instead of the site, so I want to capture the error and parse this as the test data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ansgar noted, the most recent error is at index 0.  If you want the oldest error message, which is what your original message does, you would need to subtract one from $ErrorCounter since the index is 0 based.  Or just use the built-in powershell accessor like `$ErrorResponse = $Error[-1].Exception`.  The `-1` starts from the end of the collection instead of the beginning.  You can use a negative number up to the size of your $count you computed earlier.

Comment: Thanks all for the swift reply, working now. Thanks Ansgar

Comment: Out of interest, how can you use a variable in the index like `$array[$Pointer]`

Comment: how about `$error[$array[$pointer]]`?  (And don't forget to vote for helpful answers / comments.)

Comment: That does seem to work in the command line, after I have run the code block, but the write-host does not seem to print it, its just blank. (I also have <15pts so my votes is not visible)

Comment: Do you need to do `Write-Host "$($error[$array[$pointer]])"`?  If so inside of `"`s the `$()` syntax is essentially "evalute this and replace it with the `.ToString()` of the result.